# ~5 seconds access times before Explorer displays drives

Tags: windows, ssd, windows-explorer, windows-11, windows-insider

When I open File Explorer or another program like Outlook opens File Explorer with a 'Select file' dialogue, **it takes up to 5 seconds to load the sidebar with my drives**. After that it will open Explorer fine for ~ 10 minutes after which it will load for a long time again. The data seems to be **cached temporarily**.

I am not encountering any other issues which would lead me to suspect my SSD (like lag spikes or crashes). I am running on a 6 months old Samsung 980 PRO NVMe SSD (7 GB/s seq read/write speed).

sfc /scannow yields no result. Other than that, I am clueless what to try. No new programs or any changes on system level as far as I am aware.

I am using Windows Insiders Dev (can't get out because I need to format drive for that) and hope that does not pose an issue.

Comment: I had the same (similar) issue on my own Insider machine.  I am not sure what happens as my production machines are fine. I did a reset last night and was up and running fine before the end of the evening. File Explorer is working fine now.'

Comment: remember, insider builds are basically beta versions.  even if you find a fix, it might not apply to the release.

Comment: [Disable all shell extensions](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) and try again.  If it doesn't fix the problem, put them all back.  If it does fix the problem, add them back one at a time until you find the culprit.  Every time explorer.exe opens ANYTHING, it queries each of those extensions for what it wants to do and has to wait for the answer.  Normally, it probably isn't Microsoft's fault but with an insider build, all bets are off.

Comment: I think things like a redirected documents folder (i.e. network domain location) can cause this as well. Also, enumerating external media.

Comment: remember, insider builds are basically beta versions. even if you find a fix, it might not apply  ..... To whit, my point  move on

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I disabled all non-Microsoft extensions and sadly it's still as slow as previously. When I tried disabling the Microsoft extensions the application warned me which makes sense I guess.

Comment: @Yorik Hmm, I don't have any network drives per se, but I do have a Google Drive folder sync set up. This has worked flawlessly up until now though, so I doubt it's that. Is there a way to see what happens when I open Explorer?

Comment: @Carl-LuisDressler Yes, you can use ProcMon and start with a filter on process name "explorer.exe". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: you can also try process explorer (also a sysinternals program) running as admin. 5 seconds might be long enough for you to see which application is stalling.